# Color Change by Case

Tags: c#, colors, richtextbox

I am trying to list the data from the text editor in data.txt in a RichTextBox box according to a specific form. My data.txt file consists of 4 columns. According to the data in the first column, the data in columns 2 and 3 will be coloring. For example, according to the "kmy" data in column 1; The data in column 2 is "k", the data in column 2 is red, the data in column 3 is "m", the data in column 3 is blue, and the data in column 4 is "y", so I try to list the data in column 4 in green as richtextbox.

Here are my codes;

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
    }

}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt").ToList();
        foreach (string current in lines)
        {
            string[] dataArray = current.Split(' ');
            string color1;
            string color2;
            string color3;

            Color color11;
            Color color22;
            Color color33;

            if (count % 2 == 0) { 
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            }
            count++;

            color1 = dataArray[0].Substring(0, 1);
            color2 = dataArray[0].Substring(1, 1);
            color3 = dataArray[0].Substring(2, 1);

            if (color1 == "k")
            {
                color11 = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (color1 == "m")
            {
                color11 = Color.Blue;
            }
            else if (color1 == "y")
            {
                color11 = Color.Green;
            }

            if (color2 == "k")
            {
                color22 = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (color2 == "m")
            {
                color22 = Color.Blue;
            }
            else if (color2 == "y")
            {
                color22 = Color.Green;
            }

            if (color3 == "k")
            {
                color33 = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (color3 == "m")
            {
                color33 = Color.Blue;
            }
            else if (color3 == "y")
            {
                color33 = Color.Green;
            }

            richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[1] + " ", Color.Red);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[2] + " ", Color.Blue);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[3] + " ", Color.Green);
            richTextBox1.AppendText("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[1] + " ", Color.Red);
richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[2] + " ", Color.Blue);
richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[3] + " ", Color.Green);
```

My data.txt;

```
kmy USA Washington 212
ymy England London 123
```

k red, m blue y green.
USA red Washington blue and 212 must be green

How can I print colors with color11, color22, color33 tee in Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green parts?

I am having difficulty expressing it because of my language problem. I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: are u trying to change the `RichTextBox`s foreground color ?

Comment: So you want to change the *color of the text* ?

Comment: The current code is changing the color of the richtextbox. I want to change the color of the text according to the data in column 1 in the data.txt I want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see it,are u trying to do something like this ?

```
 richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[1] + " " + "Red");
 richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[2] + " " + "Blue");
 richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[3] + " " + "Green");
```

Is this what u want ?? or you want colors in the `RichTextBox` ?? If u want colors in the rich textbox,your easiest approach would be to create a 3 pictures with 3 different colors and then just paste the pictures in the richtextbox :

```
 image img = Image.FromFile(FilePathHere);
 Clipboard.SetImage(img);
 richtextbox1.Paste();
```

or do u want to change the foreground color of the text of the richtextbox ?

```
 richtextbox1.ForeColor = color.Red
```

to combine with ur code,just do this :

```
  richtextbox1.ForeColor = Color.Red
  richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[1] + " ")
  richtextbox1.ForeColor = Color.Blue
  richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[2] + " ")
  richtextbox1.ForeColor = Color.Green
  richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[3] + " ")
```

Comment: It will color according to the situation in your if cycle.

Comment: richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[1] + " " + color11);
richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[1] + " " + color22);
richTextBox1.AppendText(dataArray[1] + " " + color33);
like this.